# AWS Serverless - Can I configure my provider or lambda function in my serverless.yml file to use an API Gateway resource in the same yml file?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, serverless

I am having a little bit of trouble figuring this bit out. I want to define an API Gateway resource in my serverless.yml and then any lamdba functions I create with an http event will use that API resource.

The reason I am doing this is that I have serveral services defined separately that I want to group under the one API, yet in my main API, include lambda functions that interact with my applications data. While these services will be used in the application, the services perform several different types of operations and it makes sense to keep them separate.

My serverless.yml is pretty straight forward, but each time I deploy it, 2 APIs are created. One that is blank and is the one I define under my resources and the second it the one that AWS creates because of my lamdba function.

```
# NOTE: update this with your service name
frameworkVersion: '^2.28.7'
service: web-api

# Create an optimized package for our functions
package:
  individually: true

plugins:
  - serverless-bundle # Package our functions with Webpack
  - serverless-offline

custom:
  stage: ${opt:stage, self:provider.stage}

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs12.x
  stage: ${opt:stage, 'dev'}
  region: ${opt:region, 'us-east-2'}
  apiGateway:
    restApiId: xxxxxxxxxx # <--- there is where I am having trouble
    restApiRootResourceId: xxxxxxxxxx # <--- there is where I am having trouble
  environment:
    VERSION: 'v1'

functions:
  getAbout:
    handler: src/api/about/get.main
    events:
      - http:
          path: /about
          method: get
          cors: true

resources:
  Resources:
    WebApiGW:
      Type: AWS::ApiGateway::RestApi
      Properties:
        Name: '${self:provider.stage}-${self:service}'

  Outputs:
    apiGatewayRestApiId:
      Value:
        Ref: WebApiGW
      Export:
        Name: WebApiGateway-restApiId

    apiGatewayRestApiRootResourceId:
      Value:
        Fn::GetAtt:
          - WebApiGW
          - RootResourceId
      Export:
        Name: WebApiGateway-rootResourceId
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Serverless Framework perspective, **is not possible to reference** dynamic values from the `Resources` section because they are still to be generated. The `provider` section will be loaded first to define how every other resource will be created. That's why you can only set static values or values loaded from environment variables in `provider`.

By default, if **you do not set** a value for `provider.apiGateway.restApiId`, Serverless Framework will generated a new API for you.

To solve the problem that you described, you need to generate an API Gateway first in a different stack and use the IDs generated by this stack in your `serverless.yaml`.

There's a nice walk through in the Serverless Framework documentation showing an example of how to break down your API in small modules (or groups as you said).

In GitHub:

- https://github.com/serverless/serverless/blob/master/docs/providers/aws/events/apigateway.md#share-api-gateway-and-api-resources

Or in the website:

- https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/events/apigateway/#share-api-gateway-and-api-resources

They create a `serverless-base.yaml` to define an API Gateway and export the IDS, then define two services, `serverless-a.yaml` for ServiceA and `serverless-b.yaml` for ServiceB, where they will use the API Gateway generated by `serverless-base.yaml`.

Comment: Hi. This is helpful as it confirmed my suspicion and that it is not possible in the way I described. It looks like I will have to create the API in a separate stack. This does seem cumbersome, but I understand the reason why this is necessary. Also, I have already read the two links, which are a great place to start.

Answer (score 0):

You should try adding api resources and use them in your functions as mentioned below.

[example to bind api resources](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PufXU.png)

I am not sure if we need to put API gateway under resources, as the event http will create it for you already.